# Relationship between differential forms and cross products

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why can the wedge product $dx\wedge  dy$ be viewed as $\vec{i}\times \vec{j}=$the standard unit vector $ \vec{k}$?

Comment: That's in three dimensions and Cartesian coordinates only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that both $\wedge$ and $\times$ are antisymmetric and bilinear (the former is it at least for 1-forms). However, $\times$ is only defined in 3 dimensions. In general we have an [exterior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), also denoted by $\wedge$, where $u \wedge v$ can be identified with the subspace spanned by $u$ and $v$ together with an orientation of this subspace and a number $|u| |v| \sin\theta(u,v)$ where $\theta(u,v)$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$. Then $\times$ can be seen of exchanging the subspace, which is a plane, with its normal given by the orientation, times the number.

The identification of $dx \wedge dy$ with $\vec i \times \vec j = \vec k$ follows if we identify $dx$ with $\hat x = \vec i$ and $dy$ with $\hat y = \vec j$.